# removing part of the url using .htacess but redirect to original URL internally

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have modified the href link using `preg_replace`

for example the original link is
`http://testdomain/test/save20`

to
`http://testdomain/save20`

but when I click on this link I still get `http://testdomain/test/save20`

besides I only want to change it in the browser like

`http://testdomain/save20`
but internally it should continue to use the url

`http://testdomain/test/save20`

I have tried in .htaccess like this

`RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/?$ /test=$1 [NC,L]`

but it doesn't seems to have any effect.

The full code in `.htaccess` is like this:

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# 

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/?$ /test=$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I am still getting like `http://testdomain/test/save20` on clicking the link. I want the url to be change to `http://testdomain/save20`